# How to set an וnchangeable iPhone passcode with IPCU?

Tags: iphone, configuration, passwords, utility, mdm

I want to add a profile to iPhone, and that the profile will set a passcode for example:
1234

And that the user, who is using the iPhone, will not be able to change this passcode.
For example, if I give it to my staff, and I wanna keep the device with a "hard to guess" passcode, and prevent staff from changing it to "1234" etc...

http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg25/scaled.php?server=25&filename=photoejg.jpg&res=landing

What I found is:
That under MDM > Security > Change device password.
But how is it working? I have mandatory fields that I have no idea what to fill in them (SERVER URL, TOPIC)

Thanks for helping guys.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set an unchangeable passcode with the iPhone Configuration Utility. The "MDM > Security > Change device password" setting you refer to, is an Access Right in the MDM Payload. If set, it allows the MDM server to to issue the 'DeviceLock' and the 'ClearPasscode' commands.